# How to call a function from a header file

Tags: c++, function, header

How do you call a function from a source file from a header file?

//h.h

```
extern string pic;
class takePic
{
public:
    void warPic();
    void artPic();
    void fatePic();
    void painPic();
    void noPic();
};
```

// second part of the same header where it calls the function
    takePic picture;

```
void pictureType()
{
    if (pic == "war")
    {
        picture.warPic();
    }
    else if (pic == "fate")
    {
        picture.fatePic();
    }
    else if (pic == "pain")
    {
        picture.painPic();
    }
    else if (pic == "art")
    {
        picture.artPic();
    }
    else
    {
        picture.noPic();
    }
}
```

When I do this it says that the linker is not working.
This is the error linker command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: Did you provide a definition for all of the functions in the header file?

Comment: "it says the linker is not working"  Post the exact error.

Comment: For a question like this, you should post more code and the exact error

Comment: Also, exert some effort to try to understand the error messages yourself.  They are surely telling you *exactly* what the problem is, which will lead you to the solution.  If you are going to be a programmer, you're going to have to be able to read and understand compiler errors.

Comment: Here is the error linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: @mattbat131:  Come on.  Scroll up a bit.  Find the *first* error.  Exert some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you change

```
void pictureType()
```

to

```
inline void pictureType()
```

You should really tell us the whole error message, and perhaps try searching for that before asking a question.